# How to count vowels and consonants and capitalizing first letter in a string while output using a method and return result

Tags: java, string, methods, return-value

If a user enters a string:  `hello there`

it should output

```
Hello has 2 vowels
There has 3 consonants.
```

I know this is a fairly simple code but I am getting too many ideas and getting confused.
I need a to make sure I have 2 methods for numberofVowels and capitalizeWord and both returns a result

I am getting an error and I am still trying to figure out to capitalize after I got counting vowels work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hwk9
{
        public static void main (String args[]) 
        {
                Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
                String string1;
                System.out.println("Enter a string");
                string1 = stdin.nextLine();
                string1 = string1.toLowerCase();

        }
        public static int numberVowels(String string1)
        {

                int count = 0;
                int vowels = 0;
                int consonants = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++)
                {
                        char ch = string1.charAt(i);
                        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || 
                                        ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                        {
                                vowels++;
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                                consonants++;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Note : Don't forget that 'y' can also be a vowel.

Comment: Are you sure ZouZou? And what error are you getting Edrick?

Comment: What error are you getting, and on which line?

Comment: @Chris Yes, sometimes it is. For example, in the word "happy" it can be considered as a vowel (even if it's often used as a consonant).

Comment: How about äöü? By the way, you're getting an error because you promised to return an int value from numberVowels but didn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler way of doing this, hope this helps:

```
public static void checkVowels(String s){
    System.out.println("Vowel Count: " + (s.length() - s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u|", "").length()));
    //Also eliminating spaces, if any for the consonant count
    System.out.println("Consonant Count: " + (s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o| |u", "").length()));
}
```

Comment: Here is a simpler version for your vowel counter: `s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^aoiuye]","").length();`

Answer (score 1):

Made something like this hope this helps, this will give vowels,consonants of each word

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
        {
                Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
                String string1;
                System.out.println("Enter a string");
                string1 = stdin.nextLine();
                string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
                int count = 0;
                int vowels = 0;
                int consonants = 0;
                for (String retval: string1.split(" ")){
                     for (int i = 0; i < retval.length(); i++)
                {
                        char ch = retval.charAt(i);
                        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || 
                                        ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                        {
                                vowels++;
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                                consonants++;
                        }
                }
            System.out.println(retval.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + retval.substring(1)+" has "+vowels+" vowels and "+consonants+" cosonants");
         vowels=0;
         consonants=0;
      }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

My code without scanner and maybe not very simple, but:

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "qwertyYVTA";
    test = test.trim();
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;

    Pattern patternVow = Pattern.compile("[eyuioa]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher matcherVow = patternVow.matcher(test);
    while (matcherVow.find()) {
        vowels++;
    }

    Pattern patternCons = Pattern.compile("[wrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher matcherCons = patternCons.matcher(test);
    while (matcherCons.find()) {
        consonants++;
    }
    System.out.println("Vowels in test String is " + vowels);
    System.out.println("Consonants in test String is " + consonants);
    }
}
```

Comment: Y can be vowel sometimes, needs special code to count it as vowel than just normal pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you;

- to create a final vowels array,
- define a `bool isVowel(char c)` function and use it in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

following code will give you vowel and Constonent count

```
static String VOWEL_GROUP = "AEIOUaeiou";
static String testString = "AAAASHMAIOUAXCCDIOUGGGGA"; // say this is your text

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vovelCount = 0;
     int consonantCount = 0;
    for (int j = testString.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {//outer loop 
        for (int i = 0; i < VOWEL_GROUP.length(); i++) { //inner loop
            if (VOWEL_GROUP.charAt(i) == testString.charAt(j)) {
                vovelCount++; //vowel count in text
                break;
            }else{
                consonantCount ++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vovelCount+" "+ consonantCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code for counting the number of vowels using recursion

```
 public static int vowels(String s){
        int count =0;
        char c;
        if(s.length()==0){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            c =s.charAt(0);
            if(c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u'){
                count++;
            }
            return count+vowels(s.substring(1));


        }
    }
```

Comment: It will not work. There is not countVowel function and the parameter passed is not correct

Answer (score 0):

This looks way simple than above answers. It gets the input, converts it to lowercase then to an array of characters. A simple for loop will do the trick onwards.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FindVowelsConsonents {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vowels_count = 0;
    int consonents_count = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    String str2 = str.toLowerCase();
    char[] chr = str2.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<chr.length;i++){
        if(chr[i] == 'a' || chr[i]== 'e' || chr[i] == 'i' || 
                              chr[i] == 'o' || chr[i] == 'u')
            vowels_count++;
        else
            consonents_count++;
    }

    System.out.println(vowels_count+ " "+consonents_count); 
    sc.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned you can use StringTokenizer:

```
    String text = "dupalo twoja mama";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text,"aeiuo",false);
    int vowels = tokenizer.countTokens();
    System.out.println(vowels);
```

In this case of "text" it will print out 7.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//don't use space in between the input string;

 class StrRev {

    static String Vowels ="aeiouAEIOU";

    public static void main(String[] args){
         @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
         String nm = name.nextLine();

         System.out.println();
         int vowel=0;
         int consonant=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nm.length();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Vowels.length();j++){
                if(Vowels.charAt(j)==nm.charAt(i)){
                    vowel++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        consonant = nm.length()-vowel;
        System.out.println("no of Vowels :"+vowel+"\nno of consonant :"+consonant);
     }

}
```

Comment: kindly explain the answer also so that future readers can be benefitted